# How to ensure a Cement board wall that is only supported on the floor (without ceiling fixing) is stable?

Tags: drywall, cement-board

I have a client that is requesting to construct a 1.8m (6ft) high wall around the back entrance of an apartment.

This wall will be in a U-shape (Plan wise) with 2m (6ft) length sides and 5m(16ft) length wall between these 2 sides.

We are discussing on the possibility of using 9mm cement board with 0.5mm Steel  studs and tracks, 60cm(23.5") stud spacing with 60cm(23.5") bracing along 2 tracks(top and bottom)

Attached a plan showing the same. Would love to hear your feedback on this and if this is sufficient to avoid having it wobble or if we need a stiffener in critical areas like the mid span and corners.

This is a residential apartment building where the client intends to convert the building's air well into dedicated terraces for the apartments surrounding the Air well. This wall will be floor mounted and will not have a roof or shed above it . It is not a guard or a hand rail, it is merely a wall to distinct the boundaries of each apartment's terrace.

[image]

Comment: Obviously, you are not US based (many, though not all, of those who regularly answer questions are), so it would be most helpful to [edit] your question to indicate where in the world you are. Also, defining what "GI 0.5 mm studs and tracks" are would help too. My guess is they're what we'd call "steel studs", but that's open for interpretation. Your 60cm (23.5") spacing may or may not work - what does your local building code specify? My guess is that since cement board (that I'm familiar with) is rather fragile and would be likely to crack when bumped at that spacing.

Comment: What's going _over_ the cement board? What function will it serve?

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to the top channel. 5 meters is a long span for sheet metal. If there's no other stiffening cap or anything involved, I'd expect it to be a bit sproingy. (That's a word.) You'll need something very stiff at the top, or you'll need a center post (or two) of some sort.

It really has nothing to do with the cement board, though. The movement won't be enough to affect it, nor will it add much stiffness itself, beyond what inertia its mass lends. Now, if you're installing ceramic or some other hyper-rigid covering, that's where you'll have problems. Any bounce will result in cracking.

Then there's the issue that FreeMan mentioned--the stud interval. I'd reduce that to the next common distance. Two or three more studs won't break the bank and you'll have a more durable surface.